# What theorem can I use to decide if an ODE which admits separation of variables has a unique solution?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that I have the IVP : $$y' = f(x)g(y)$$
$$y(a)=b$$

It's easy to show that any solution of such an equation will satisfy the implicit formula: $$ \int \frac{1}{g(y)}dy = \int f(x) dx$$

I would like to know if there is a theorem of existence or uniqueness for an IVP like the one above.

Answer (score 0):

The standard Picard-Lindelöf-Cauchy-Lipschitz [existence and uniqueness theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) will apply as long as $f$ is continuous and $g$ is locally Lipschitz.

Answer (score 0):

The [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) helps in such cases.

However, it is easy to construct solutions which do not have a unique solution, i.e. the theorem is not applicable.

Consider for example $y^\prime(x) = x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ where $y(0)=0$.

Then a solution is $y_1(x)=0$ and two others are $y_{2,3}(x) = \pm \left(\frac 23 x\right)^{\frac 32}$.